# Does Zabbix support wildcards in conditions (for actions)?

Tags: zabbix, wildcard

For example, if you go to `Configuration` > `Actions` > choose or create one > `Conditions (tab)`. Then in "New condition", choose: `Trigger name`, like, [hello foo bar].

Can I use a wildcard to match the trigger name, say `hello%foo bar` or `hello*foo bar`?

What is the wildcard character then?

Answer (score 1):

There are no wildcard triggers in Zabbix.

When you need to do something incredibly repetitive like this, it can be easier to export the template and edit the resulting XML by hand; scripting or copy/pasting and editing what you need, and then importing it back in.